# How can I find where a user has clicked on a Polyline?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

If I add a Polyline to my map with a click function:

```
    onPolylineClick = (props, polyline) => {
        console.log(props)
        console.log(polyline)
    }

    <Polyline
        onClick={this.onPolylineClick}
        path={gpsCoords}
    />
```

Then how do I figure out where on the line it was clicked? I can see `props.mapCenter` but that doesn't change depending on where I click, it's just the centre of the map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add marker onClick and show my geolocation in google-maps-react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421714/how-to-add-marker-onclick-and-show-my-geolocation-in-google-maps-react)

Comment: @Nick no, I read that before I asked the question. That answer is for an onClick event from the map which doesn't tell me if the line was clicked. I want an onClick event from the line itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also pass a third parameter in your onPolylineClick since the latLng for the point you clicked in the polyline is there. You can do something like:

```
onPolylineClick = (props, polyline, e) => {
   console.log("Polyline Clicked on latlng: ")
   console.log(e.latLng.lat()+","+e.latLng.lng());
  };
```

You can check this [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/onpolylineclick-5jpki). Make sure to add your API Key in the GoogleApiWrapper for the code to properly run.

Comment: That works great, but how do I handle a Polyline with more than one segment? Can I tell which segment the user has clicked?

Comment: You can use a for loop to go through each segment and use [isLocationOnEdge()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge) of Google Maps JavaScript Geometry library to check which segment does the clicked point is nearer or lies to. Here's a [sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/onpolylineclick-uhcwh). Take note however that this function has tolerance that might also result to showing the other nearest segment. If this would be your use case, I think you need to create multiple <Polyline /> for each of your segments to be more accurate.